# Play In-app Billing v3 - Should I save purchase tokens?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

so I'm writing an android app with a special in-app currency. You can buy this currency in packets of 1, 5, 10 etc through in-app billing. Here is how I implemented it:

1. Use managed products (When the app starts, I use IabHelper to query for purchased products)
2. As soon as the purchase completes, consume the purchase
3. When consumption finishes, send purchase token to the server
4. Server checks through play API, and then provisions the account with the currency

My question is, what if step 3 fails? If the connection gets cut off or something, the purchase token will never get to my server. In that case, users will have paid for currency but their account won't get it. When my app starts again, and 1a runs, it won't find the purchase and it won't re-consume it either.

Is this reasoning correct? If so, do I need to store purchase tokens on the android side? Then, if something fails, I keep retrying until it works? It seems kind of messy... I was also thinking of making a  "My purchases page" where you could see all your purchases, and then click them to redeem it if step 3 failed for some reason.

Comment: "When my app starts again, and 1a runs" where is 1a?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should keep `purchaseToken` on your backend. There are two reasons to do so:

- block repeated purchases
- keep track of consumed purchases

The scenario to consume a purchase should look like this:

1. Send purchase to your backend
2. Save `purchaseToken`
3. Increase user balance (virtual currency)
4. Send back infomation about successful operation

Once you've received successful response from your backend, you should consume the item on Android side. If you've already added the virtual currency on your backend (without consuming the item) you should also return successful response so the item will be consumed without increasing user balance.

Keep in mind that it's very easy to repeat **the same** purchase even if it's already been consumed so `purchaseToken` **must be** validated every time on your backend. If it already exists in your DB just do not increase the virtual currency.

Comment: Thanks, I do keep my purchase tokens on my backend. But I was wondering if it was also necessary to keep it on the front end(inside the android app). Because, what if the connection fails right when it's sending the purchase token? Should I store it somewhere and send it later? Or does that rarely happen?

Comment: This situation will not happen in the scenario I've posted as the answer. You consume the in-app item after it has been successfully added on the backend side. The in-app item contains the `purchaseToken` so there's no need to keep duplicate of it in another place. There's no way the purchase is lost even though the connection has failed or your app has crashed.

Comment: @tomrozb you said that the `purchaseToken` is contained within the item and that there's no reason to keep a duplicate. But how can you retrieve the token if the purchase has already been made?

Comment: @JMRC You don't have to keep copy of a `purchaseToken` on your device,  but of course you have to save it on your backend to prevent repeated purchases. To retrieve the purchase token just query your inventory for purchased items. Every item has its own `purchaseToken`. You cannot do this once the item is consumed, that's why you keep track of it on your backend.

Comment: @tomrozb When do you make the purchase and retrieve the token? Before point 1? Or between 1 and 2 which would mean that step 1 is a verification that the server is up and running.

Comment: @JMRC Before point 1. First user have to make a purchase then you will be provided with all the purchase data.

Comment: @tomrozb What if the backend fails? The purchase has already been made.

Comment: @JMRC You consume the item after it has been successfully added to the backend. I don't see any drawbacks here. If the backend is offline you simply do not consume the item but you can consume it once the backend is online again.

Comment: @tomrozb When you first purchase an item the user has already paid when you receive the token. So if the backend fails you can't send the token. Right?

Comment: @JMRC Of course you can't send token to the backend which is offline at given moment, but you can send it later. You receive purchase once user has paid for it. Sorry but I cannot explain you all the in-app billing basics and describe the entire flow. Please read the in-app billing guide available at the developer.android.com then ask a separate question.

Comment: @JMRC: I did, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412171/storing-google-play-in-app-purchase-token-in-backend, but it's not very active. I misunderstood your original answer, I thought you were describing a convenient alternative.

Comment: @tomrozb the problem here is that documentation says the opposite:
"Important: BEFORE provisioning the consumable managed product in your application, you must send a consumption request to Google Play and receive a successful response indicating that the consumption was recorded"
(https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume)